# How can I format the output of "to" in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetime

I'm a citizen of Brazil and people here use time in the following format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS". I have two bootstrap datepickers ("begin date", "end date" and a field for hours and minutes). I need to display how much time there is from begin date (current time) to the end date (with the specified time). After suffering a lot with Date(), I'm now using moment.js, and I'm using [to](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/).

Here's my code:

```
$("#PedidoDateFimHour").on("change blur", function() {
    aSplit = $("#PedidoDateIniData").val().split('/');
    bSplit = $("#PedidoDateFimData").val().split('/');
    time = $("#PedidoDateFimHour").val().split(':');
    hour = parseInt(time[0]);
    min = parseInt(time[1]);
    a = moment(aSplit[0] + '-' + aSplit[1] + '-' + aSplit[2], "DD-MM-YYYY");
    a.add(moment().hour(), 'h').add(moment().minutes(), 'm');
    b = moment(bSplit[0] + '-' + bSplit[1] + '-' + bSplit[2], "DD-MM-YYYY");
    b.add(hour, 'h').add(min, 'm');
    alert(a.to(b));
});
```

**a** is the "begin date" with current time, and **b** is the "end date" with the specified time. The result of this is "in a day" or "in 3 days", "in 2 hours", etc. I need the output of my country "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS", formatted, and format() does not work on this function (to). As it seems, it does not return a new moment object. How can I format the output?

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't it be easier to just do `new Date(aSplit[2], aSplit[1], aSplit[0])`, compare date objects, and output, and how exactly do you show a time difference in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` ?

Comment: The main problem is that I have to calculate the difference in hours and minutes, and display a formatted output.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd display the difference in that format, but I'll give it a try -> **http://jsfiddle.net/e2sn8os9/3/**